# Wordpress - After Moving post some post didn't show feature image

Tags: wordpress

I have 2 sites on wordpress(Lets assume SiteA and SiteB), both sites having 100+ posts with feature image. Now i want to merge/move all post from SiteB to SiteA. For this i use wordpress's Tools>Export and Tools>Import. I export all post and media as well from siteB and then import them in SiteA with attachments.
All post are import successfully but the problem is some post show attached feature image and some are not. Whereas all images are completely imported to media. 
Kindly help me regarding this issue... 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below forum comments it will work with given step:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/257180/how-to-import-wordpress-posts-with-images-from-one-wordpress-site-to-another